# Cordova（android）で動画再生のため、端末内部でwebサーバを立ち上げたが、オフラインになると再生できない

Tags: android, webview, cordova, 動画

### Cordovaでandroidの開発をしています。

動画再生について質問です。

#### 【目的】

Cordovaで作成したアプリ内でvideoタグを使用してhtml内部で動画を再生させたい。
Android 5.0では動作したが、Android 4.4.2でWebViewを使用した場合に再生できない。

#### 【問題点】

動画が100秒までしか再生できない。

#### 【使ってるライブラリ等々】

1. Cordova（androidで開発）
2. File API（Cordova plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file）
3. inappbrowser（Cordova plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser）
4. CorHttpd（Cordova plugin https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd）

#### 【経緯】

動画の再生のため、CordovaプラグインのFile APIを使って

```
/data/data/<app-id>/files/
```

以下にファイルを配置し、そこで動画を再生していたのですが、100秒までしか再生できませんでした。

動画へのアクセスがfileプロトコルだったので、httpプロトコルでのアクセスにしようとcordova.httpdプラグインを使用して、android内部でwebサーバを立ち上げました。
同時にfileプロトコルからhttpプロトコルへのアクセスはできないため、inappbrowserプラグインを使用して、別windowを立ち上げ、その内部で、video再生用HTMLを表示させていました。

```
http://192.168.2.1:8080/sample/sample.html
```

として、アクセスできます。

ここで問題が出ました。
android端末がwifiに接続されていた場合（オンライン時）は動画が全て再生されるのですが、
wifiに繋がっていない場合は上記のような100秒までしか再生できない現象になります。
オフライン時は

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample/sample.html
```

へのアクセスになります。

chromeのadb exentionを使用して、つながっているandroidのWeb Viewのデバッグができるので、そこでログ追っていると、動画ファイル読み込みが、`(pending)`表示になっていました。

【目的】が達成できればよいので、手段は問わないのですが、動画を読み込ませる方法、または動画再生方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: Androidのバージョンや端末はなんでしょう。端末依存の問題ではないというのはわかっている状態なのでしょうか。読み込み側のvideoタグはどのように書いているでしょうか。<video width="400px" height="300px" autoplay controls><source src="android.resource://my.package.name/raw/videotest" type="video/mp4"></video>というようなスキームもあるようですが試されたでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘いただいたので検証端末を増やしてテストしてみました。結果正しくvideoタグが動作して最後まで視聴できる端末もありました。端末依存の面から検証してみます。ありがとうございました。
バージョンは４以上で、端末の詳細は伏せさせて下さい。検証結果を報告することで代えさせていただければと思います。videoタグの記述はご提示いただいた記述ではありませんでした。

Comment: 追加報告です。端末依存ではなくosのバージョン依存のようです。android5ならうまく再生できます。android4.4.2でinappbrowserを使用した場合、上の現象が出ます。詳細は随時書いていきます。

Comment: 質問を編集し、バージョン依存の旨追記しました。今後も何かあれば、質問を編集することでより回答が集まりやすくなります。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Crosswalkで別のactivityを立ち上げinappbrowserのかわりとすることで対応できました。詳細は後で書きます。

Answer (score 1):

[質問者 silvermotto さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/379/cordova-android-%E3%81%A7%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81-%E7%AB%AF%E6%9C%AB%E5%86%85%E9%83%A8%E3%81%A7web%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%82%92%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8C-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%95%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#comment5803_379)より。

> Crosswalkで別のactivityを立ち上げinappbrowserのかわりとすることで対応できました。